# How can I disable helm file completion for interactive shell command?

Tags: helm, shell-command

I have turned on `(helm-mode 1)` and selectively turned it off for `find-file` for default emacs behavior, which I prefer. I would also like to restore non-helm behavior for file completion when invoking `shell-command`. E.g. if I do `M-! ls ~/<tab>` it currently shows the helm completion buffer. How can I use the default emacs file navigator for `shell-command` , while keeping helm globally?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, here is to create a wrapper to turn off helm-mode for a specific command:

```lisp
(defun my-shell-command (&optional no-op)
  (interactive)
  (let ((completion-in-region-function 'completion--in-region))
    (call-interactively 'shell-command)))
  
(global-set-key "\M-!" 'my-shell-command)
```